# Can I get banned for asking questions which don't attract answers or votes?

Tags: support, post-ban

Actually, if something new comes to the market and few people know about it, they will be unable to answer my questions. I am receiving no answers, no up votes and no down votes,  will Stack Overflow block me from asking new questions?

Comment: So you're saying you received no downvotes, yet you are banned? Looking at your questions on SO, I don't see the 0-score questions you're referring to. Have you been deleting a significant amount of questions?

Comment: @Bart i am sorry, but i made a typing error , i am asking i have many such question with no votes and no answers will stackoverflow block me from asking???

Comment: @MohdSuleman The exact criteria for being question banned is not public, intentionally, to prevent abuse.

Comment: No, you only get banned if you have downvoted questions and if you delete those you get banned even faster.

Comment: So it's a hypothetical? Then no, why would they? If you don't post bad things, there's no reason to ban you. If you don't get responses or upvotes, you might want to reconsider your questions. But it's not necessarily bad enough for a ban to kick in.

Comment: @juergend It's not *just* downvotes that are taken into consideration.  Quickly deleted questions count against you, even if not downvoted, as do closures, at the very least.

Comment: and why is this question , Down Voted?  Did i make some mistake???

Comment: Well, it wasn't all that clear to begin with. But I'm just guessing that's the reason.

Comment: As you can see, CyberBoy, with [a little community wiki help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/208481/revisions) a post can be put into shape and reverse the down vote trending ;)

Comment: You won't get punished for it; SO even gives you a [shiny badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=1992269).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you ask reasonable questions which don't get answered, you won't be banned for it. Not receiving upvotes or downvotes is not an indication that you're so bad that a ban is in order. The exact details of the banning algorithm are not public, but I have yet to see a user complain who got banned for asking questions that did not receive attention.

However, if it does happen more than occasionally that your questions get no attention and no votes whatsoever, then you might have to look at what you can do to improve. Perhaps you're not clear enough. Perhaps your tags don't attract the right people. Perhaps you need to do a bit more research to make the question somewhat easier to answer.

But in general, a significant amount of bad (and possibly deleted) content will get you banned. Content that doesn't get any attention won't really have that effect.