# Are questions with no vote and/or no answer going to have a negative effect on my questioning profile in the network?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

This is not actually a duplicate of [Can I get banned for asking questions which don't attract answers or votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208481/can-i-get-banned-for-asking-questions-which-dont-attract-answers-or-votes)

I am not asking if only asking questions with no score can get someone banned from asking more questions.

On the other hand I am wondering if questions with no vote and/or no answer in combination with questions with negative scores can **eventually** get the person banned from asking more questions.

The reason I am asking this question is according to [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) it is suggested that users should demonstrate that their contributions are making the site better by their questions. But it also mentions that at least users' contribution should not make the site worse. So it is a little bit vague.

Also recently I am getting a warning which states that I am in danger of being blocked from asking any more question while I have a question with negative score of 2 (downvoted twice), a question with positive score of 2 (upvoted twice) and couple of un-voted unanswered questions.

I want to ask more questions, but I am worried that if I ask a question and it doesn't receive an upvote, I might get banned from asking any more questions.

In addition I am wondering why these rules, regarding getting banned are not published so every one can be careful not to get banned?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328898/295232) is roughly what we as community know about the formula.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you very much for the formula. Am I correct to assume that based on this rule, asking question with no vote, does not have a negative effect?

Comment: It doesn't have a positive effect and as we have no "meh" effect it must be negative.

Comment: 4 questions doesn’t seem like enough of a sample to start warning you about your question which suggests you might have deleted questions.  Having a question deleted is not a good thing, deleting a question yourself because of a downvote, is definitely not a good thing

Answer (score 6):

From the [help center article you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans):

> Edit *all of your questions*, paying special attention to those that score 0 or less. All questions are expected to be useful to future visitors,

Also, from [this faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/369802):

> So if many of your questions do not get answered, are downvoted, closed, or deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they did not meet the required quality.

So yes, we do know the ban looks at *all* of your questions, regardless of whether they're open, closed, deleted, undeleted, upvoted, downvoted or having no votes at all. See also the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328898/295232) Glorfindel sent you in the comments.

---

The rules that determine quality bans are secret, to avoid people deliberately bypassing the question control. This too is mentioned in [that faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/369802) I linked previously:

> To avoid bypassing the filter, its internal rules are a secret

You don't need the specific internal rules of the filter to *tell you when* you need to be careful, that's what the warning you're seeing is for. Take it seriously.